# Insert dynamical exam result of each student

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have problem with inserting dynamical exam into mysql database.
I don't know how to explain in word so this my code for example:

I have table exam this is my exam table structure:

exam table

```
+----+-----------+
| id | exam_name |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | run test  |
|  2 | swim test |
+----+-----------+
```

student table :

```
+----+-------------+
| id |   student   |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | student one |
|  2 | student two |
+----+-------------+
```

The problem is how to insert into table exam result, for example student one pass exam run test but fail for swim test. so the table exam result will show like this:

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| id_exam | id_student | status |
+---------+------------+--------+
|       1 |          1 |      1 |
|       2 |          1 |      0 |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

This is how i fetch every single exam and student into html table to give result of each student:

```
<table class='wp-list-table widefat fixed striped posts'>
      <tr>
        <th class="bgth manage-column ss-list-width1">Participan Name</th>
          <th class="bgth manage-column ss-list-width1">Complited Pool Requirement</th>
          <th class="bgth manage-column ss-list-width1">Complited Theory Exam</th>
          <th class="bgth manage-column ss-list-width1">Medical Sertificate Checked</th>
    <th class="bgth manage-column ss-list-width" colspan="2">Action</th>
      </tr>
  <input type='hidden' name='exam_total' value='3'><input type='hidden' name='exam_names' value='[{"id":"1","exam_name":"Complited Pool Requirement"},{"id":"2","exam_name":"Complited Theory Exam"},{"id":"3","exam_name":"Medical Sertificate Checked"}]'><tr><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>Handri angga riawan
        <input type='hidden' value='1' name='x-id[]'></td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>
          <input type='checkbox' name='Complited_Pool_Requirement[]' value='1'>check if pass
          <input type='hidden' name='id_exam[]' value='1' >
          </td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>
          <input type='checkbox' name='Complited_Theory_Exam[]' value='1'>check if pass
          <input type='hidden' name='id_exam[]' value='2' >
          </td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>
          <input type='checkbox' name='Medical_Sertificate_Checked[]' value='1'>check if pass
          <input type='hidden' name='id_exam[]' value='3' >
          </td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'><a href='#'>Delete Participan</a></td></tr><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>Suyadman
        <input type='hidden' value='2' name='x-id[]'></td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>
          <input type='checkbox' name='Complited_Pool_Requirement[]' value='1'>check if pass
          <input type='hidden' name='id_exam[]' value='1' >
          </td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>
          <input type='checkbox' name='Complited_Theory_Exam[]' value='1'>check if pass
          <input type='hidden' name='id_exam[]' value='2' >
          </td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'>
          <input type='checkbox' name='Medical_Sertificate_Checked[]' value='1'>check if pass
          <input type='hidden' name='id_exam[]' value='3' >
          </td><td class='manage-column ss-list-width'><a href='#'>Delete Participan</a></td></tr></table><p><input type="submit" id="btn" name="p-submitted" value="Save Result"></p></form>
```

How to get student id and all exam he/she pass and fail to insert into mysql table like I show below (exam result)

Answer (score 0):

your approach is correct now. as  this  like

```html
| id_exam | id_student | status |
+---------+------------+--------+
|       1 |          1 |      1 |
|       2 |          1 |      0 |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

you can just add one more column for result  ( like score ) datatype as float sot that it will allow you to insert decimal value also.

for access of student id and exam id for save result, then just add value in checkbox "check if pass" in value attribute as like

```
<input type="checkbox" value="exam_id#student_id"/>
```

on post action separate this value by # and you will get exam id and student id.

---

for display your radio button instead of checkbox like this

```
Select exam reslut
<input type="radio" name="swim_exam[]" value="exam_id#student_id#1"/> Pass
<input type="radio" name="swim_exam[]" value="exam_id#student_id#0"/> Fail

if you select pass you will get status 1 other wise get 0 with commonly exam and student id also.
```

so it should be like below code...

```
    <?php 
if(!empty($_POST['swim_exam'])){
        foreach($_POST['swim_exam'] as $swim_exam){
            $idnStatus = explode("#",$swim_exam);
            $examId = $idnStatus[0];
            $studentId = $idnStatus[1];
            $status = $idnStatus[2];

           // Your Insert query will perform here.... with all above id.
        }
    }
?>
```

try this.

Comment: the problem is how to get status of each id_exam and id_student to insert into table, please se my html snippet. :) 
anyway thanks for comment

Comment: you mean to say that, " your are not able to get exam id and student id" on save result button...?

Comment: I want to get id_student get id_exam and get status (if chacked value will 1 and if not value will be 0)

the problem is (see the exam result table) how to get status of all student exam to insert into table. Please see the example

thanks

Comment: I still don't get it

how to insert multiple row because there is multiple status for one student and exam. so i'm confusing how to get them and fetch them using php

for example :
the student one have exam (checked) like this :
run (checked), swim(checked)
it should have sql query like this right ? :
Insert into table exam_result Value (1, 1,1 ), (1,2,0)

that's i mean

thanks

Comment: i got your point, i am going to edit my answer, will add code below that one, will help you.

Comment: i think that will work but how if exam dinamically and not only insert for one student but it will insert student batch like 2 or more.

thanks :)